# onchange select box with Post Values to another page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having a table with multiple select box carrying different information in the form of variable, While selecting any of the option of the select box it is redirected to another page. I am using this statement for redirecting

```
 <select name="workno" onchange="javascript:window.location = 'form.php?workno=' + this.item(this.selectedIndex).value + '&counter=<?php echo $counter ?>&it=<?php echo $it?>&office=<?php echo urlencode($office) ?>';">
  <option value="<?php echo $record['workno'];?>"><?php echo $record['workname'];?></option
```

The above statements are working fine but the problem is the variables are passed as query string, I want to hide these variable and their values when the user move to the other page. I have also changed the form method to POST, but its not working. 
How can i do that.

Comment: FYI, `this.item(this.selectedIndex).value` can be simplified to just `this.value`. The value of a dropdown is the value of the selected option.

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting using `window.location` always sends a `GET` request, and you can't send `POST` parameters that way.

What you can do is make your `onchange` action submit the form. You can send the additional parameters using hidden inputs. And you can append the `<select>` value to the form's `action` attribute before submitting it.

```
<form method="post" action="form.php">
    <select name="workno" onchange="this.form.action += '?workno='+this.value; this.form.submit()">
        <option value="<?php echo $record['workno'];?>"><?php echo $record['workname'];?></option>
        ... other options
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="counter" value="<?php echo $counter ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="it" value="<?php echo $it ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="office" value="<?php echo $office ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: Seems to be a simple and a good solution, But i think there will be an issue. As u can see in the my code user jumps with this statement window.location = 'form.php?workno=' + this.item(this.selectedIndex).value, i.e by carrying the selected workno Which can not be carried using a hidden field as compared to other fields

Comment: `workno` will come automatically from the `<select>`, just like submitting a form normally.

Comment: Do you want `workno` to be in a `GET` variable, but everything else to be in `POST`?

Comment: yes you are right, Its working, No i don't want the workno to be GET variable.

Comment: I checked but there is an issue its working for the last select box in the form. Not for all. As i told its table and in each row there is a select box of workno. With your suggestion its working for the select box in the last row

Comment: If you have multiple controls with the same name in a form, they all get sent to the server, but `$_POST['name']` can only hold one of them, so it gets the last one.

Comment: You could do it by deleting all the select boxes other than the one you selected from before submitting the form. That's easy to write with jQuery, but will be verbose in plain JS. You should move it out to a separate function, it won't fit into an `onchange` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the form method to `POST` won't work. You need to use **AJAX** to send data to server using POST method.

Using **jQuery** in this example might help you very much.

What you need to do is bind change event on select box using [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) and then perofmr [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request inside function.

Normal syntax of **.ajax()**  is as follow.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', //GET is also accepted.
    url: YOUR_URL_TO_POST_DATA,
    data:{'datakey':datavalue}, // Pass your all data here
    beforeSend: function() {
      // This function will trigger before sending AJAX request.
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
      // This function will trigger after successful AJAX request. 
    },
    error: function(e,textStatus)
    {
      // This function will trigger if there is any error during AJAX request.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can enclose your `select` in `form` `tag` and then use `javascript` to `submit` your `form`. use `action` to send your form in `form.php` like this

```
<form method="post" action="form.php">
    <select name="workno" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="<?php echo $record['workno'];?>"><?php echo $record['workname'];?>
            </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="counter" value="<?php echo $counter ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="it" value="<?php echo $it ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="office" value="<?php echo $office ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: Seems to be a simple and a good solution, But i think there will be an issue. As u can see in the my code user jumps with this statement window.location = 'form.php?workno=' + this.item(this.selectedIndex).value, i.e by carrying the selected workno Which can not be carried using a hidden field as compared to other fields

Comment: @Ricky no will also get your selected option value by $_POST['workno'] in form.php

Comment: Yes its working, checked but there is an issue its working for the last select box in the form. Not for all. As i told its table and in each row there is a select box of workno. With your suggestion its working for the select box in the last row

Comment: @Ricky i don't know why its not working in your cas please check it i have answered a new simple code for you though its different from your question but it will clear you that selecting any option in any row form is submitted. Please copy and run my code

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Try this just for clear your doubt**

```
index.php

<?php 
$counter = 100;
$it = 101;
$office = 102;
 ?>

<table border="1px solid black">
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Sub</th><th>Action</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Mamta</td><td>PHP</td><td><form method="post" action="form.php">
    <select name="workno" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="">--Select---</option><option value="1">one</option><option value="2">two</option></select>         
    <input type="hidden" name="counter" value="<?php echo $counter ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="it" value="<?php echo $it ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="office" value="<?php echo $office ?>">
</form></td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Shipra</td><td>HTML</td><td><form method="post" action="form.php">
    <select name="workno" onchange="this.form.submit()">
      <option value="">--Select---</option><option value="3">three</option><option value="3">four</option></select>         
    <input type="hidden" name="counter" value="<?php echo $counter ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="it" value="<?php echo $it ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="office" value="<?php echo $office ?>">
</form></td></tr>
</table>




 form.php

<?php
echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);
```